# Parallelize in Cython without GIL

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, cython, hpc

I'm trying to compute some columns of a `numpy` array, operating on python objects (`numpy` array) in a for loop using a `cdef` function.

**I would like to do it in parallel.** But not sure how to.

Here is a toy example, one `def` function calls a `cdef` function in a for loop using **`prange`**, which is not allowed because `np.ndarray` is a python object. In my real problem, one matrix and one vector are the arguments of the `cdef` function, and some `numpy` matrix operations are performed, like `np.linalg.pinv()` (which I guess is actually the bottleneck).

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from cython.parallel import prange
from c_functions import estimate_coef_linear_regression

DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t

def transpose_example(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] data):
    """
    Transposes a matrix. It does each row independently and parallel
    """

    cdef Py_ssize_t n = data.shape[0]
    cdef Py_ssize_t t = data.shape[1]

    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim = 2] results = np.zeros((t, n))

    cdef Py_ssize_t i

    for i in prange(n, nogil=True):
        results[i, :] = transpose_vector(data[:, i])

    return results

cdef transpose_vector(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] vector):
    """
    transposes a np vector
    """
    return vector.transpose()

a = np.random.rand(100, 20)
transpose_example(a)
```

outputs

```
Converting to Python object not allowed without gil
```

**What would be the best way to do this in parallel?**

Comment: You need to get the underlying storage of the numpy array and do the processing manually, preferably in C or C++.

Comment: @Xbel Let me notify you, that your recent edit is not a polishing touch to add a few, merely unimportant, details. **It has FATALLY changed the Problem-under-Review**. Please, kindly consider to rather use the StackOverflow policy - to rather open a new question, instead of creeping and moving the original "target". There you ought opt to define a whole MCVE, both shape-s & dtype-s of the recently introduced **1D-`vector` & 2D-`np.ndarray`** +all the relevant processing (not restricted to a context-less mentioning "just" a call to `np.linalg.pinv()`) which you aim to get parallelised. Thanks

Comment: @user3666197 I'm not really sure of that. I have used intentionally `np.transpose()` to show that I have to use a python object. Actually, it is understood this way by the unique answer. So not really sure that it *FATALLY changes the Problem-under-Review*. I'm gonna accept the answer because it helps me to understand where the problem was. An probably can help other people to know the limits of `prange`and not using `GIL`.

Comment: As you already know, the below **benchmark**-measured Answer proves, that you ought rather be sure that **`prange`**-decorated vector-moves will but spoil the **native `~16 [us]`** ( any-[GB]-sized ) **performance** of the `np.transpose()` and that any other function than FATALLY changes the Problem-under-Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass typed memoryview slices (`cdef transpose_vector(DTYPE_t[:] vector)`) around without the GIL - it's one of the key advantages of the newer typed memoryview syntax over `np.ndarray`.

However,

- You can't call Numpy member functions (like transpose) on memoryviews, unless you cast back to a Numpy array (`np.asarray(vector)`).  This requires the GIL.
- Calling any kind of Python function (e.g. `transpose`) is going to require the GIL. This can be done inside a `with gil:` block, but when that block is almost your entire loop that becomes pretty pointless.
- You don't specify a return type for `transpose_vector`, and so it'll default to `object`, which requires the GIL. You could specify a Cython return type, but I suspect even returning a memoryview slice may require some reference counting somewhere.
- Be careful not to have multiple threads overwriting the same data in your passed memoryview slice.

In summary: memoryview slices, but bear in mind you're quite limited in what you can do without the GIL. Your current example just isn't parallelizable (but this may be mostly because it's a toy example).

Comment: Then is not parallelizable. Would you recommend me to use Joblib in regular python function?

Comment: @Xbel Why did you click **Accept** on an answer, that promotes a thing, that **does not** solve your original problem, but the very contrary - explicitly **confirms, that you cannot use a promoted technique for a defined goal?**

Comment: @user3666197 I assume because of the following quote: `Your current example just isn't parallelizable (but this may be mostly because it's a toy example)`, which fully answers the question.

Comment: @user3666197 I found it really accurate and has helped me a lot to understand why I cannot do it this way. But certainly, you are right in the sense that it does not solve entirely what I ask for. Not sure what is the policy in these cases

Comment: @NarūnasK yes, that was my thought.

Comment: @user3666197 OP is of course not obliged to accept my answer. I think an answer that says "you can't do it and this is why..." should be acceptable (if true). I also think it's worth waiting at least a day or two to accept such an answer, in case anyone has any better ideas

Comment: @DavidW. Ok, I see your points here. I'll wait and see if someone else provides a better answer.

Comment: @Xbel About `joblib`. For this toy example I wouldn't bother. 1) Simply copying memory tends not to parallelize well, and 2) if it did work it's quite likely Numpy would already have made the 2D array transpose work in parallel internally. It's harder to say for your "real" use-case since I don't know anything about it.

Comment: I have edited the post to include more information. I guess I should have designed better the toy example, but change it now wouldn't be fair.

Comment: @Xbel I think internally Numpy tries to do its calculations in parallel where possible, so if you look at the CPU usage you might find it's already running in parallel. If not, then Scipy provides a Cython BLAS and Lapack interface that lets you access the C/Fortran functions than actually do the array operations. These won't require the GIL so can be used in parallel.

Comment: @DavidW I respect your argument from the answer & also accept your statements in the recent comments, yet - I hope we both recognise - the proposed technology does not direct O/P towards any parallel-computing approach, does it? This said, I have also to **remind the O/P, that the StackOverflow strongly *discourages* to creep the original Question**. The best next step would be to open another question, with a fully defined problem, not deflecting efforts to a toy-problem, which happened not to be a compatible representation of the actual problem to solve. This is the StackOverflow way of work

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"What would be **the best way to do this** in parallel?"*
> +
> *"[I have used intentionally **`np.transpose()`** to show that I have to use a python object.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156167/parallelize-in-cython-without-gil?noredirect=1#comment104566993_59156167)"*

Let me start with freely paraphrasing the fabulous Henry FORD's maxim: ***the least defective part of an automobile is the very one, which is not there at all*** - it can never get damaged.

Those, who know how the **`numpy`**'s internal array-object representation works are sure,
 it **takes** <sub>*almost*</sub> **zero time**
and
it **requires** <sub>*almost*</sub> **zero memory-I/Os** <sub>( at least for the last decade or so it did )</sub>

---

### WHY ?

**Numpy is smart**.
It does not move any data for this at all. It just adapts the indexing at a cost of about **`15 [us]`**

---

### ANSWER :

**The Best Ever way to do the `np.transpose()`** does not need any parallelisation at all.

Any attempt to do so will result in a way poorer performance, due to artificially enforced many useless memory-I/O-s that the native `np.transpose()` never does - it just swaps indexing-scheme, without moving the heaps of cell-data, all rest in their original places (incl. keeping any and all cache-coherences valid - so any next access is going to take place **`0.5 ~ 5 [ns]`** from cache, not having to pay again immense amounts of many times **`150-350 [ns]`** for moving any cell-data from/to physical RAM-locations and devastating the cache-lines)

---

### THE PROOF :

**`______1x THE PROBLEM SIZE   100 x   20 x 8 [B]`** `( 16 kB RAM).transpose() ~ 17 [us]`

```
>>> r =   100; c =   20; a = np.arange(r*c).reshape( (r,c) );a.itemsize*a.size/1E6
0.016
>>> aClk.start(); _ = a.transpose(); aClk.stop()  ####  16   [kB] RAM-footprint
17                                                ####  17   [us] !!! ZERO-COPY
```

---

**`____100x THE PROBLEM SIZE  1000 x  200 x 8 [B]`** `(1.6 MB RAM).transpose() ~ 17 [us]`

```
>>> r =  1000; c =  200; a = np.arange(r*c).reshape( (r,c) );a.itemsize*a.size/1E6
1.6
>>> aClk.start(); _ = a.transpose(); aClk.stop()  ####   1.6 [MB] RAM-footprint
17                                                ####  17   [us] !!! ZERO-COPY
```

---

**`__10000x THE PROBLEM SIZE 10000 x 2000 x 8 [B]`** `(160 MB RAM).transpose() ~ 16 [us]`

```
>>> r = 10000; c = 2000; a = np.arange(r*c).reshape( (r,c) );a.itemsize*a.size/1E6
160.0
>>> aClk.start(); _ = a.transpose(); aClk.stop()  #### 160.0 [MB] RAM-footprint
16                                                ####  16   [us] !!! ZERO-COPY
```

Moving or ALAP-allocating & copying that many RAM-stored megabytes of cell-data, as does any **`prange`**-d or whatever else code would do, will take ages, not the smart **`16 [ns]`** as the smart numpy-design does.

---

```
>>> a.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS    : True <-------------------------ORIGINAL [indirect] RAM-indexing
  F_CONTIGUOUS    : False
  OWNDATA         : False
  WRITEABLE       : True
  ALIGNED         : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY    : False
>>>
>>> _.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS    : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS    : True <------------------------TRANSPOSE'd
  OWNDATA         : False
  WRITEABLE       : True
  ALIGNED         : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY    : False
```

---

Q.E.D.

---

### EPILOGUE :

Now comes the point behind the [notice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156167/parallelize-in-cython-without-gil?noredirect=1#comment104550410_59156167) clear and sound. Hopefully that.